# How to configure the order of appearance of the widget buttons in the GNOME desktop top bar drop-down menu

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I notice that the Power button and the Logout button can get switched, occasionally. I do not know the cause of this phenomenon. I would like the Power button to always be on the extreme right always. The logout button was enabled by [a Gnome extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1143/logout-button/).

How do I make this configuration?

[image: Topbar drop-down menu]

Comment: "When l0gut butt0n extension exists" in this case you want the p0wer butt0n at the end?? It seems you also somehow managed the Suspend button but did not provide the link.. I understand that when two extensions Logout button and Suspend button extensions are enabled Y0u want the p0wer button at last??

Comment: @PRATAP The Suspend button was enabled using this other [GNOME shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/). Yes, I want the power button to be always the first from the right (or last if one is counting from the left).